# How do I typecast a void * pointer in C++?

Tags: c++, casting

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    float _t100;
    void * _t200;
    float _t300;
    _t100 = -5.0;
    _t200 = &_t100;
    _t300 = *(float *)&_t200;
    cout<<_t300;
    return 0;
}
```

It prints -1.61669. Why? It should print -5.0.

Comment: `_t200` is most definitely not a `float`, pretending it is cannot lead to anything good.

Comment: @Deduplicator could you elaborate? I don't see anything wrong with type casting `void*` to `float*` when you know it's actually pointing to a float.

Comment: _t200 = &_t100; what this statement means is that: _t200 contains a reference to the address of _t100 and so if you change _t100 you are also changing _t200 because they are both pointing to the same address and value. However &_t200 is a reference to the address of the variable void *_t200 which is unknown. You meant to write, where *_t200 pointer is pointing to.

Answer (score 5):

It's because `&_t200` is the address of `_t200`. Since `_t200` is a `void*`, its address is a `void **`.

I think you meant to do

```
_t300 = *(float*)_t200;
```

By the way, symbols beginning with `_` are reserved; you should not name variables this way.

Comment: only in the global scope, or if the second character is uppercase. Anyway: `union {void* p;float x;}; *(float*)&p = .1f;` would be perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra `&` in your code: this line

```
_t300 = *(float *)&_t200;
```

does not need an ampersand, because `_t200` is already a pointer:

```
_t300 = *(float *)_t200;
```

[demo](http://ideone.com/R5HHzq).

Answer (score 1):

Your error is here:

`_t300 = *(float *)&_t200;`

You are taking the address of `_t200`, making it a `void**`, so when you print it you're actually printing the address of `t_200`

Answer (score 1):

In your code you're not casting a `void*` - you're casting `&_t200`, which is a `void**`. If you leave out the `&`, you get the result you want.

Answer (score 1):

This expresison

```
*(float *) &_t200;
```

reinterprets the memory occupied by the pointer `_t200` as a `float` object and evaluates to that `float` value. I.e. `-1.61669` that you see is the content of the pointer `_t200` itself (i.e. an address) reinterpreted as `float`.

This is probably not what you wanted to do.

If you want to get access to your original `-5.0` value stored in `_t100`, you have to reinterpret the memory `_t200` *is pointing to*, not the memory `_t200` occupies itself. The following expression

```
*(float *) _t200;
```

would do exactly that.